# Destroying components

Tags: javascript, extjs

If I create a container with an identifying variable, I know, how to remove it:

```
var item1 = Ext.create("Ext.container.Container",{...});
item1.remove();
```

What if the element has been created this way:

```
Ext.onReady (function () {    
    Ext.create ("Ext.container.Container",{
        html: "Raw Component",
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });  
}
```

How can I remove this element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are trying to *destroy* the container(*remove* method is to remove components from the container).

One way to destroy is to use itemId and ComponentQuery

```
Ext.onReady (function () {    
    Ext.create ("Ext.container.Container",{
        itemId: 'myContainer',
        html: "Raw Component",
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });  
}

var myContainerRef = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myContainer');
myContainerRef[0].destroy();
```